# The weight of something in a specific gravity field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, mass, weight

I am working on a project in my free time and need to know what the weight of a person who has a mass of 70 kg in a gravitational environment of 0.1035773536599592926 pound-force would be.

Comment: Nobody has that kind of precision in measuring gravity. What is your uncertainty on that number? Also, mixing systems of units is never a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

A gravitational field is normally described by the gravitational acceleration. This is just the acceleration that an object experiences if you let it fall freely. So for example the gravitational acceleration at the surface of the Earth is approximately $9.81$ m/s$^2$ and we normally call this $g$.

The weight of an object is simply the mass multiplied by the gravitational acceleration, so on the Earth's surface the weight of an object with mass $m$ is:

$$ W = mg $$

The weight is a force, so the units of weight are the same as the units of force i.e. Newtons.

When you say:

> 0.1035773536599592926 pound-force

I'm guessing that you mean a gravitational acceleration in which a pound weights $0.1036...$ pounds, which means the gravitational acceleration of this field is:

$$ a = 0.1036 \,g $$

(I've rounded to 4 significant figures for convenience)

So in the field the weight of an object with mass $m$ will be:

$$ W = ma = 0.1036 \,mg $$

Just put $g = 9.81$ m/s$^2$ and $m = 70$ kg into this equation to get the weight.

Comment: I'm sorry. I am incredibly new to this, and you kinda lost me at "W=ma=0.1036mg
 
Just put g=9.81g m/s22 and m=70 kg into this equation to get the weight."
and just so you dont think im trying to cheat my way out of a homework assignment. this project has nothing to do with schooling just a spare time   project.

Comment: are you saying that it would be 0.1036*9.81*70=71.14212?

Comment: @emerald: yes. Or at least *yes* provided my interpretation of your question is correct.